# ATK4 Fatal Error

Tags: atk4

Fatal error: Class 'h1' not found in /home/iracersr/public_html/atk4/lib/AbstractObject.php on line 131

I have installed the latest version and here is the code im using. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
class page_index extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $p=$this;
        //Get Articles
        $articles=$this->add('Model_News')->getRows();

        $p->add('h1')->set('Latest News');

        foreach($articles as $article){
            $content=$this->add('view',null,null,array('view/blog'));
            $content->template->set('title',$article['title']);
            $content->template->set('content',$article['content']);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's case sensitive.

```
->add('H1');
```